# ExtJS how to get exception from spring conrolerAdvice handler

Tags: java, spring, extjs, exception

On the server I am handling exceptions globally using @ControllerAdvice
CODE:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalExeptionHandler
{
    public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class,RuntimeException.class})
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler (HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        mav.addObject("datetime", new Date());
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());       
        return mav;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {UnableToSaveException.class})
    public ModelAndView saveExceptionHandler (HttpServletRequest request, UnableToSaveException e)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);

        mav.addObject("errCode", e.getErrCode());
        mav.addObject("errMsg", e.getErrMsg());

        return mav;
    }
}
```

I know that using ExtJS on client I can catch exception using this code:

```
  Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options, eOpts) 
{
...
}
```

I want to rise dialog with error Message which I want to get from `ModelAndView` which is returned in spring, but I do not know how to get it. Can someone tell me how, or say if I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should be able to get it from the response parameter passed in the requestexception handler. Have you debugged to see the properties available on this?

Comment: I cannot find any parameters in 'response' which I set for the 'ModelAndView mav'